# An unhandled exception occured while processing the request in asp.net core 3.0 web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to run NET Core 3.0 WebAPI project but I getting the following error

```
An unhandled exception occured while processing the request in asp.net 
core 3.0 web api
```

[error msg click here to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLuia.jpg)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Did you read the details and checked your application regarding the described thing to check?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error you are getting, this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]}")]//the example have extra `}` here 
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Produces the following error:

> Check that each '{' character has a matching '}' character.

You need to check your attribute routing of your `WeatherForecastController` and its `Get` action to find whether there is any extra `{`/`}` or you are missing brackets.

Comment: '{' missing brackets in another controller and thanks for suggestion "Xing Zou"

Comment: @Vikas Great..Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved the problem